# Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried this with both a class component:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    x = 3;
    componentDidMount () {
        fetch(apiURL).then(() => {
            x = 5;                
        });
    }

    render () {  
        return <div>{x}</div>;
    }
}
```

and using a function component:

```
let x = 3;
fetch(apiURL).then(() => {
    x = 5;                
});

const Foo = () => <div>{x}</div>;
```

And the value of x shown on the page never changes, or seems to change randomly. What gives?

Comment: Related [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395910/is-there-a-canonical-dupe-target-for-illegally-mutating-variables-in-react?noredirect=1#comment762534_395910).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React only knows to re-render when you tell it something changed, by using the facilities it provides for state management:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    // In class components state must be an object
    state = {
        x: 3,
    };
    componentDidMount () {
        fetch(apiURL).then(() => {
            // Note that we change state with the setState method.
            this.setState({ x: 5 });               
        });
    }

    render () {
        return <div>{this.state.x}</div>;
    }
}
```

additionally function components should be *pure* (no side-effects) so to update them React gives us hooks:

```
const Foo = () => {
    const [x, setX] = useState(3);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(apiURL).then(() => {
            // We use the setter returned from useState.
            setX(5);               
        });
    }, []);

    return <div>{x}</div>;
}
```

So you can't just assign to a variable and expect React to know: you have to use it's update functions so it knows it needs to re-render that data to the page.