# variables are not reassigning after running useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

so i have these 2 elements defined at the beginning

```
let interestElm = (
    <Row
      title={translate('calculator.interest')}
      value={translate('currency_amount', {
        amount: offer.totalInterest,
      })}
    />
  );
  let commisionElm = (
    <Row
      title={translate('calculator.commission')}
      value={translate('currency_amount', {
        amount: offer.newInitialCommission,
      })}
    />
  );
```

then when rendering the page useEffect runs this function

```
useEffect(()=>{
    discountElemHandler(discountData)
  }, [discountData, amount])
```

this function checks some values and they they exist the variables should be re-assigned

```
const discountElemHandler = (discount) => {
    if (discount.length) {
      discount.forEach(discountItem => {
        if (discountItem.type === 'Type1') {
          interestElm = (
            <Row
              inheritStyle={style.discount}
              title={translate('calculator.interest')}
              discount={translate('currency_amount', {
                amount: offer.newInterest + discountItem.amount,
              })}
              value={translate('currency_amount', {
                amount: offer.totalInterest,
              })}
            />
          );
        }

        if (discountItem.type === 'Type2') {
          commisionElm = (
            <Row
              inheritStyle={style.discount}
              title={translate('calculator.commission')}
              discount={translate('currency_amount', {
                amount: offer.newInitialCommission + discountItem.amount,
              })}
              value={translate('currency_amount', {
                amount: offer.newInitialCommission,
              })}
            />
          );
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

i can see on the debugger that the conditions are met for the function but for some reason the re-assignment doesn't take place ?

anyone can help me with that ?
thank you loads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: @JaredSmith well the issue is not the state because most of the data in the element is rendered from a state so it should automatically invoke a re-render when it changes, but even when i put the whole elm in state i still face the same issue!

Comment: Would be useful if you provide the RENDER method, so we can see what/how are you actually rendering your JSX

Comment: @LamisAbouzina you are trying to modify a closed-over variable instead of putting in state, meaning it's a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect is called after the render method finishes drawing on the screen. Meaning that if you wish to trigger a new render, after the useEffect has run, you need to trigger a STATE change.
I suggest that you should either define your two let variables as STATE or you should store some other type of data in the state, which will be used within those two vars.

Comment: actually offer , discount, discountData and almost all parts of the elements are from several states