# pass data into component with 'let' keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to pass some data into my FlatList component after running a graphql query. If I hard-code data using `const DATA`it works. However, if I define two cases (successful query and unsuccessful query) and use `let DATA`, the variables aren't passed into the FlatList properly and they are always undefined inside FlatList component.

How can I fix this? **How can I ensure that `DATA` is passed into the `FlatList`only after the query has been run?**

For example, hard coded data like this works:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    imageUrl: defaultUrl,
    name: 'Friend',
    vehicles: [],
    rating: 1,
    numberOfFriends: 3,
  }
];
```

But this doesn't (query works fine though):

```
let DATA;
 const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
    onCompleted: () => {
      console.log('frineds', data.me.friends)
      DATA = data.me.friends.map(
        (item: {
            firstName: string;
            id: number;
            rating: number;
            vehicles: Array<Vehicle>;
            friends: Array<User>;
          
        }) => ({
          id: item.id,
          imageUrl: defaultUrl,
          name: item.firstName,
          rating: item.rating,
          //vehicles: item.vehicles,
          vehicles: [],
          numberOfFriends: item.friends.length,
        }),
      );
    },
    onError: ()=> {
          DATA = [
            {
              id: '1',
              imageUrl: defaultUrl,
              name: 'Friend',
              vehicles: [],
              rating: 1,
              numberOfFriends: 3,
            }
        }
  });
```

FlatList:

```
        <FlatList
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={DATA}
          horizontal={true}
          //scrollEnabled
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <WhitelistItem
              title={item.name}
              face={item.imageUrl}
              firstName={item.name}
              rating={item.rating}
              numberOfFriends={item.numberOfFriends}
              vehicles={item.vehicles}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
```

Edit:

I know about setStates but does this guarantee that every time the query re-runs, the data will be updated? Or do I necessarily have to use **useEffect** etc? In the past when I have used useStates, the data was often not updated automatically and kept giving old data so I was looking for an alternative way

Comment: you should use hooks in that case, as thats the only way to update your component to render new incoming data, there is also the option of force updating the component but that one is not reliable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`you should use hooks or class based state in that case, as thats the only way to update your component to render new incoming data, there is also the option of force updating the component but that one is not reliable`

using useState hook you can set DATA variable and rerender the component to fill the array

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const YourComponent = () => {

    const [DATA, setDATA] = useState([]);


    const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
        onCompleted: () => {
          console.log('frineds', data.me.friends)
          let tmpData = data.me.friends.map((
              item: {
                firstName: string;
                id: number;
                rating: number;
                vehicles: Array<Vehicle>;
                friends: Array<User>;
              
            }) => ({
              id: item.id,
              imageUrl: defaultUrl,
              name: item.firstName,
              rating: item.rating,
              //vehicles: item.vehicles,
              vehicles: [],
              numberOfFriends: item.friends.length,
            }),
          );

          setDATA(tmpData)
        },
        onError: ()=> {
            tmpData = [{
                  id: '1',
                  imageUrl: defaultUrl,
                  name: 'Friend',
                  vehicles: [],
                  rating: 1,
                  numberOfFriends: 3,
            }]

            setDATA(tmpData)
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Does this guarantee that every time the query re-runs, the data will be updated? In the past when I have used useStates, the data was often not updated automatically and kept giving old data

Comment: well if the query re runs, that goes through this HOC useGetMyProfileQuery, since you already include a function to update the data in this case 'setDATA' function, that pretty much will guarantee that the state will be reset to the new data which means the component will re-render

Comment: but is it possible that the the old ```data```will be passed to the ```flatList```again, before the new data is set?

Comment: Also, for the ``` setDATA(tmpData)```on the ```onError```case, I get an error that ```argument of this type is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.```If I change ```useState([]);``` to ```useState<any>()```then it works without an error but using ```any```. isn't a good idea

Comment: it is not possible that the old data will be passed because you are storing them on the state, unless you set the state with the old data, but that is not happening on the code as you are setting the new state on the callback results. 

you are using typescript thats why you get type casting errors, I wrote it on javascript which doesnt have static types. You're good with using <any>

Answer (score 0):

Here, When you pass DATA to flatlist, it is not getting the values at that time. That's why you get the error while passing the DATA.

You should wait somehow until the DATA gets the required values.
You can also bind the rendering of flatlist based on the condition.