# Reactjs not showing the dynamic data generated from state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, public

I'm facing problem looping through javascript array of objects on reactjs component. The chrome browser inspect view giving this output from console.log ---

```
0: {id: 1, title: "This is a post 1"}
1: {id: 2, title: "This is a post 2"}
2: {id: 3, title: "This is a post 3"}
3: {id: 4, title: "This is a post 4"}
4: {id: 5, title: "This is a post 5"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I've stored the json files inside public folder like the following ---

```
public
--post-data
----posts.json
----1.json
----2.json
----3.json
----4.json
----5.json
```

posts.json file ---

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

1.json file ---

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "This is a post 1"
}
```

Here's my data fetch functions ---

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    Container, Row, Col, Jumbotron
} from 'reactstrap';

class HomePage extends Component {

    state = { posts: [] }

    getPost(path) {
        axios.get(path)
            .then(res => (this.state.posts.push(res.data)));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('./post-data/posts.json')
            .then(response => response.data.map((value) => (
                this.getPost('./post-data/' + value + '.json')
            )));
        console.log(this.state.posts);
    }

    render() {

        const listItems = this.state.posts.map((data, key) =>
            <Col lg={{ size: 4 }} className="mb-3">{key}</Col>
        );

        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.state.posts ? <section>
                    <Container>
                        <Row>
                            {listItems}
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                </section> : <p>No posts found!</p>}
            </Fragment>
        )
    }

}

export default HomePage;
```

But nothing's showing on screen. Help me please!

Comment: `this.state.posts.push(res.data)` Data on state should be immutable, i.e. you should copy `this.state.posts` and push onto that new array.  Also, you should use `setState` instead of making changes to `this.state` directly.  By setting the state directly the way you are, React is not made aware of the change in state and therefore doesn't know to re-render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: @benbotto brother, how can I setState in my scenario? Can you elaborate please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you are missing brackets in your **render return**, try:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        {this.state.posts ? (<section> 
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    {listItems}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </section>) : (<p>No posts found!</p>)}
    </Fragment>
)
```

Basically the difference is in your conditional return, each section is marked with brackets `condition ? (return 1) : (return 2)`

Also, you may have an issue as you are attempting to mutate the state directly in `this.getPost()` you should instead of `this.state.posts.push(something)` you should use `this.setState()` so you would write `this.setState(prev => ({posts: [...prev.posts, something]}))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setState otherwise a re-render doesn’t get called.

Change your getPost method to this:

```
getPost(path) {
    axios.get(path)
        .then(res => this.setState({posts: this.state.posts.concat([res.data])}))
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right since that sets the single post in `res.data` to the array of `posts` on state.

Comment: Yes. setState is not storing all the data of each json file.

Comment: Have updated my answer, I misunderstood what your api returned