# React JS V17.0.0: Cannot assign to read only property 'color' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am new to React JS, I want to dynamically change the color of h1 tag based on click event in React JS. I have tried it and here is the [StackBliz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w5qwcr?file=src%2FApp.js).

When I am trying to update the style object I am getting `Error: Cannot assign to read only property color of object`.

I tried many solutions that are posted in stackoverflow but none of them helped me solve this issue. Please help me out.

**App.js**

```js
    import React from "react";
    import "./style.css";
    
    export default function App() {
      const style = {
        color: "coral"
      };
    
      const changeColor = () => {
        style.color = style.color === "coral" ? "gray" : "coral";
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => changeColor()}>Change Color</button>
          <h1 style={style}>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
          <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Here is the solution I tried which did not work out.

```js
    Object.defineProperties(style, {
      color: {
        value: "coral",
        writable: true
      }
    });
```

Comment: Assign color to state, update it using setState

Comment: Okay @AlexanderStaroselsky I will try that and get back to you.
Thank you

Comment: I didn’t see you have a functional component, use useState hook to manage state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: @JaredSmith That did not answer my question, It did not tell the cause of that specific error. Even though my problem has been solved using state but it would be better if I get more specific answer about the error. Thank You

Comment: @SaiSurya the entire idea of React is that your views are pure functions of your application state. "Pure" has a very [specific meaning for a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), and your function is not pure. In prior versions of React you just wouldn't see the change, the new version throws an error. All of this is very well covered by the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use static variables to change virtual DOM.

use `useState` to change your color.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qkmqcu?file=src%2FApp.js

**Explanation**

as I told you, you specified read-only const in DOM and you can not mutate it, whenever you click on the button, you must need to rerender your virtual DOM and for that, you must to assign your color into state and error also tells that you can not assign anything that changeable ( means its read-only )

Comment: Thank You so much. Using state solved the problem but can you please tell me about the cause of the error I mentioned.