# react setState not updating the state on the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have an array of items. when I type in the item number in my UI, the item will be added to the array and being displayed. I console logged and saw the item is being added into the array, but not displaying on the UI.

for example, I currently have items 1, 2, 3, 4 in array as [1, 2, 3, 4]. When I add a 5, the array will get updated as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], but 5 is not displaying on the UI.

This is the relevant code:

```
export const generateItemsState = (prevState, itemErrors, testItems) => {
   const { project, items, updatedProject, validationErrors } = prevState;
   const newState = {};
   
   if (itemErrors && itemErrors.length) {
      // irelevant
   } else {
      // no item errors
      newState.updatedProject = Object.assign(updatedProject, { items: testItems });
   }
   return newState;
}
```

```
setItemsInStateAfterValidation(itemErrors, changedTestItems) {
   const newState = generateItemsState(
      this.state,
      itemErrors,
      changedTestItems
   );

   if (!itemErrors || !itemErrors.length) {
      this.setState(newState, () => {
        this.props.onUpdate(
           this.state.updatedProject
        )
      });
   } else {
      this.setState(newState);
   }
}
```

Please give me some guidence, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: You have `newState.updatedPorject = ...` which is a typo (pORject vs pROject) and should be `newState.updatedProject`. Did you make that mistake only when posting here, or is that copied from the original code?

Comment: it was typo, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You've mutated state:

```
  newState.updatedPorject = Object.assign(updatedProject, { items: testItems });
```

First rule of react, don't mutate state. It should be:

```
  newState.updatedPorject = Object.assign({}, updatedProject, { items: testItems });
```

or equivalent:

```
newState.updatedPorject = { ...updatedPorject, items: testItems }
```