# Unable to update React.useState("") after joining all elements in array to single string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to update a React.useState("") using setDisplay in a function that takes an array of strings and joined them into a single string before setDisplay.

Without the setDisplay, I'm able to console.log() and get the joined array.

```
const App = () => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = React.useState("");

  const values = [];
  const onClick = (value) => {
    values.push(value);
    console.log(values) // w/o setDisplay output: ["1","2","3","4"]; w/ setDisplay output: ["1"]; ["2"]; ["3"]; ["4"];
    setDisplay(values.join(""))
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-5">
      {display}
      <NumPads data={keypress} onClick={onClick} />
      <OperatorPads data={keypress} onClick={onClick} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why do you have `const values = [];` outside the `onClick` function ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika it wouldn't make much sense inside the function either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: Yes, that's true...Now I got it, In that case, OP was trying to push the values into an array variable instead of the state.

Comment: You can't do that. Any time you see `.push` or `.sort` in a React component, it's a bug. Put values in state, and only join them to display, there's no point in storing them in their joined state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `console.log` seems to work when you ***don't*** call `setDisplay` is simply because the state of the component did not change.

When you call `setDisplay`, you change the state, so the entire component re-renders, which causes `values` to reset back to an empty array.

#### Solution(s)

- One way to solve this is already shown in a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68986603/2089675) answer.
- Another way is to wrap your `values` array with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

  ```
  const values = useRef([]);
  ```

  Then access the array using `values.current`
- Yet another way is to eliminate the use of `values` all together and change the callback to:

  ```
  const onClick = (value) => {
    setDisplay(display + value);
  };
  ```

Comment: Wow, this is a very clear and concise answer, and really appreciate the clarification of console.log() due to the re-rendering of the component. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
setDisplay((values) => ([...values, value].join("")]))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I did try something like this just now but it did not work. Well, thank you for the fast response. Too fast that still not able to accept this as an answer yet still within that 10 minutes window.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue with the OP's code: they're mutating state illegally by pushing onto the values array. This will only "work" if App isn't re-rendered. See the comments on the question.

Comment: @imcodean make sure you remove the statement `values.push(value)` it does not have any use here

Comment: Yes, I have replaced it entirely with just ```const values = [];
  const onClick = (value) => {
    setDisplay((values) => [...values, value].join(""))
  };``` Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const onClick = (value) => setDisplay((dispay) => display.concat('', value));
```

Comment: Would appreciate the comment on why this answer is not useful.

Comment: Can you tell me why this comment is not useful ?

Comment: I feel like OP is asking mainly about how to do state management on a react component and it is not about using `join` or `concat`.

Comment: @imcodean can you try this solution and tell me if it's work please ?