# SetInterval can't be stopped by clearInterval when using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've tried to implement a function that starts a count down when the isPlaying variable is truthy and it stops when it's falsy, in general, it doesn't work and all it does is just start multiple intervals simultaneously,
The isPlaying changes when the video stops or start playing again

```js
 let interval
    useEffect(() => {
            if (isPlaying) {
                interval = setInterval(() => {
                    setTimePassed((time) => time + 1)
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                console.log('clear interval');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }, [isPlaying])
```

Comment: You can't use closure variables that way in React. If you want to persist state (like the value of a `setInterval` handle) in a function component use `useState`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't think this is case here, here interval is just used to keep track of id returned from setInterval so that it can be passed to clearInterval, though it's not possible to answer, unless OP provides code where isPlaying is mentioned.

Comment: @CodeManiac why would a variable in a closure persist across multiple different calls? React makes no guarantees about when it re-renders your FCs and `clearInterval` will happily take `null` or `undefined` and no-op. That's literally what hooks were created for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, I just put the interval outside the boundaries of the function and referred to the _id when clear interval.

```js
let interval = null
export default function PlayerBar() {
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useRecoilState(store.playingState)
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState(100)
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState<number>()
    const [timePassed, setTimePassed] = useState<number>(0)
    // const [intervalStatus, setIntervalStatus] = useState<any>()
    const player = useRef<any>()
    const timePassedStatus = useMemo(() => duration - timePassed, [timePassed])
    const durationStatus = useMemo(() => ('' + (duration / 60)).split('.').join(':'), [duration])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                setTimePassed((time) => time + 1)
            }, 1000);
        }else if(interval){
            clearInterval(interval._id)
        }
        return () => {clearInterval(interval)};
    }, [isPlaying])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to store your interval in the useRef hook as component rerender s your interval value is set to undefine as it does not retain the state

```
let interval = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying) {
          interval.current = setInterval(() => {
                setTimePassed((time) => time + 1)
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            console.log('clear interval');
            clearInterval(interval.current);
        }
        return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
    }, [isPlaying])
```