# React component doesn't update after onClick

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

In my project I have some arrow icons (contained in the `Skill` component) and when you click on them it changes their className. To check if the component has been clicked I used a boolean array as state, so when the onClick event is fired it toggle the state of the component.
The states change correctly but the component does not update the class and rendering takes place (as well as during mounting) only after the first click.

The page code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Skill from '../../components/skill/skill.component';
import { skills } from './skills';

import './about-page.styles.scss';

const AboutPage = () => {
    console.log('render')
    const [cache, setCache] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCache(new Array(skills.length).fill(false))   
    }, []);

    const onToggleFunc = n => {
        cache[n] = !cache[n]; 
        setCache(cache);
        console.log(cache);
    }

    return ( 
        <div className='about-page'>                
            <div className='container'> 
                {
                    skills.map((x, i) => (
                        <Skill 
                            isToggled={cache[i]} 
                            skillName={x.name} 
                            onClickFunc={() => (onToggleFunc(i))}
                            key={i}                         
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AboutPage;
```

the Skill component code:

```
import './skill.styles.scss';
import icon from '../../assets/icons/arrow.png';

const Skill = ({ isToggled, skillName, onClickFunc }) => (
    <div className='skill-item'>
        <img src={icon} alt='icon' 
            className={`icon ${isToggled ? 'toggled' : '' }`} 
            onClick={onClickFunc}
        />
        <span className='desc'>{skillName}</span>
    </div>
)

export default Skill;
```

[Here](https://ibb.co/Zxhgd6n) the browser console

Comment: you're mutating state, so when you `setCache(cache)` React doesn't know it's updated and therefore doesn't rerender. You should create a new array with the appropriate value changed and pass that to `setCache`. Rather than type up how to do it I'll try to find a similar question on SO with answers, there are going to be several good ones I'm sure as this is a common mistake/question/problem!

Comment: [struggling to find a good one, which surprises me! Anyway I see someone else has now given an answer based on this.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm not sure that's a helpful duplicate. In that question the OP isn't using state at all - here they are, but it's not updating due to them directly mutating it rather than passing a new object to setState. It's not the same scenario, and the one here is I think much more common - so it's surprising to me that there isn't a "canonical" duplicate for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must **never** mutate a state variable, you must instead create a new reference and update the state variable by calling the updater method.

```
const AboutPage = () => {
    const [cache, setCache] = useState(() => new Array(skills.length).fill(false));

    function onToggleFunc(n) {
      // create a new array from the previous one
      setCache(prevCache => prevCache.map((val, i) => i !== n ? val : !val));
    }

    return ( 
      <div className='about-page'>                
        <div className='container'> 
          {
            skills.map((x, i) => (
              <Skill 
                key={i}
                isToggled={cache[i]} 
                skillName={x.name} 
                onClickFunc={() => onToggleFunc(i)}                         
              />
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default AboutPage;
```

Comment: thanks! Now it' s working