# Use state in React causing value of const to break

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, use-state

I'm trying to make an app where the user can cycle through a pack of cards. I'm trying to make it so each card is unique so that a user cannot pick two of the same card consecutively. Therefore the way I thought of doing this was by adding all the cards to an array and then shuffling that array.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import homeStyles from "../styles/homeStyles";
import { cardsList } from "../assets/cardsList";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [CurrentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(1);
  const [usedQuestions, setUsedQuestions] = useState([]);
  const test = [];

  const length = cardsList.length;

  const shuffle = () => {
    let i,
      x = 0,
      y = 0,
      temp0 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < usedQuestions.length; i++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * usedQuestions.length);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * usedQuestions.length);
      if (x === y) {
        //for dont change arr[index] with self !!!
        continue;
      }
      temp0 = usedQuestions[x];
      usedQuestions[x] = usedQuestions[y];
      usedQuestions[y] = temp0;
    }
    console.log("Shuffled : " + usedQuestions);
  };

  let i = 0;
  const nextQuestion = () => {
    let plz = null;
    if (i <= usedQuestions.length) {
      // plz = usedQuestions[i]
      setCurrentQuestion(usedQuestions[i]);
      i = i + 1;
    } else {
      i = 0;
      // shuffle()
      // nextQuestion()
    }
    // console.log(plz)
    console.log(CurrentQuestion);
  };

  const start = () => {
    let i = 1;
    while (i <= length) {
      test.push(i);
      i++;
    }
    console.log("initial : " + test);
    setUsedQuestions([...usedQuestions, ...test]);
  };

  return (
    <View style={homeStyles.container}>
      <View style={homeStyles.card}>
        {cardsList
          .filter(function (item) {
            return item.id === CurrentQuestion;
          })
          .map((cardsList) => {
            return (
              <View key={cardsList.id}>
                <View style={homeStyles.line}>
                  <Text style={homeStyles.cardNumber}>
                    {cardsList.id}) {cardsList.title}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={homeStyles.cardText}>{cardsList.cardText}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        <Button
          style={homeStyles.button}
          title="Shuffle"
          onPress={() => shuffle()}
        />
        <Button
          style={homeStyles.button}
          title="Next Question"
          onPress={() => nextQuestion()}
        />
        <Button
          id="test"
          style={homeStyles.button}
          title="Start"
          onPress={() => start()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The section below is the section causing me issues

```js
let i = 0;
const nextQuestion = () => {
  let plz = null;
  if (i <= usedQuestions.length) {
    // plz = usedQuestions[i]
    setCurrentQuestion(usedQuestions[i]);
    i = i + 1;
  } else {
    i = 0;
    // shuffle()
    // nextQuestion()
  }
  // console.log(plz)
  console.log(CurrentQuestion);
};
```

The const plz works perfectly returning the value of the cards one by one from the shuffled array. See Image [image: Const plz working]

However when I try and use the UseState feature from react to set this value so that I can use it to display the correct part in the app section it breaks. [image: Use state breaks value]

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it? I'm fairly new to coding so any tips on how I could better it would be appreactiated.

Comment: You cannot mutate state in functional React components. My advice, since you asked for it (and not just for you), is to **stop using React. Seriously**. Not because there's anything wrong with React, but because it's a tool for experienced professional developers and it (and it's documentation) will assume you know things that as a beginner you won't know (like what mutation and functional mean in this context). I mean this in the same way that if we were talking about learning flying instead of coding I'd suggest you start with a Cessna instead of a 747.

Comment: Further reading about the problem you're experiencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly

Comment: @JaredSmith This is React is taught to beginners, the docs don't ask you to understand everything happening under the hood as long as you understand a bit of JS and follow a set of rules. Also, I don't think OP was asking for opinions but more for technical tips to help him get better and learn. ✌️

Comment: @Apolo I know, and beginners very understandably want to know things that will help them get a job, and this will continue as long as the incentives are aligned that way no matter how much it doesn't make any sense. That doesn't mean I have to like it, and as someone who follows this tag and sees the same question over and over day after day it gets frustrating. And my advice *is* technical advice that will help the OP get better: superficial understanding of a momentarily popular framework might get one past a first interview but if one wants to actually last a deeper understanding is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, this is an exercise preparing me for my final project for university this year which will be in React (June time) so I have to use it, unfortunately. Therefore all the advice is greatly appreciated. However for the future what alternative would you recommend me using instead of React to help me learn the basics first?

Comment: @JacPhillipps depends on your career trajectory and what you want to do but learning how to use plain Javascript/HTML/CSS first as far as frontend goes. Headache first, *then* aspirin. But if you had to take any courses in functional programming in your curriculum (scheme, SML, haskell, whatever) then remember that React has way more of that kind of flavor and you'll be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a state directly

You can create a copy, shuffle it and reassign the state in this way

```
const shuffle = () => {
   setUsedQuestion(u => {
    const data = [...u]
    data.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5))
    console.log("Shuffled : " + data);
    return data;
    }
   )
}
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand. My shuffle section works fine with useState. Its my nextQuestion function that doesnt work. When I uncomment the plz constant it works fine. As it displays the shuffled cards 1 by 1 as seen by the first picture. However when I try and assign the same value in a useState it doesnt work see picture 2. And I need it in a useState I believe to access it in the android section. See the filter and map section after the return. As I want to show each shuffled card on the screen.

Comment: Good advice here. Actually in theory it's possible to mutate the state object but strongly discouraged.

Comment: @JacPhillipps "My shuffle section works fine with useState" no, it doesn't. It *coincidentally* works, and there is no guarantee that it will continue to do so, because you are violating the contract that says that your functional components must be pure (no mutation). And if you don't understand what any of that means that's *fine*, it doesn't make you a bad person or even a bad coder but it does mean that you are going to struggle mightly with React.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I think I get what you mean now and this way of shuffling the array works much better thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you update a react state (eg. by calling setCurrentQuestion) your component will rerender.
Here, rerendering means it will execute the code of your function component again (`function Home()`).
In the body of `function Home()` you have this: `let i = 0;` so `i` will reset everytime you change a local state.

Now what you probably want is to persist the current question index across multiple rerenders.

you could do `nextQuestion` like this:

```js
// remove: const [CurrentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(1);
const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
const currentQuestion = usedQuestions[currentQuestionIndex];

const nextQuestion = () => {
  if (currentQuestionIndex < usedQuestions.length) {
    setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex + 1);
  } else {
    setCurrentQuestionIndex(0);
  }
};
```

You might have more tweaking to do but that should get you started

Comment: This works perfectly and solves the issue thank you so much :)