# ReactJS doesn't display content from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I fetch data from Firebase and then push that data to array with components. I am trying to display that by using the following code but React displays nothing, also there are no errors in console and during compiling.

```
import React, { useState ,useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import db from "./firebase";
import { doc, getDocs, getDoc, collection, query, orderBy, limit, where } from "firebase/firestore";


function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    getdata();
  }, []);

  const names = []

  async function getdata() {
    getDocs(collection(db,'questions')).then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        names.push(<p className="question" >{doc.id}</p>)
        Object.values(doc.data()).forEach( test => {
          names.push(<p className="answer" >{test}</p>)
        });
      });
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {names}
    </div>
  )
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add complete code of the component? Do you have `useEffect()` hook anywhere?

Comment: the code is finished before your `getDocs` function/promise execute. You need to save them into a state

Comment: You're missing the concept of "state" in React, which is fundamental to how that framework works.  It sounds like what you're looking for are introductory tutorials on React.

Comment: You need to use useState and useEffect hook to handle the scenario - https://elevateprogramming.blogspot.com/2022/09/react-code-snippets.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is React not rendering my component state correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940633/why-is-react-not-rendering-my-component-state-correctly)

Comment: Sorry, now I provided complete code of my component, I already used UseEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce `state` into your app.

Put your items into state, and then render JSX from your state

```js
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import db from './firebase';

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  async function getdata() {
    const snapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'questions'));

    const items = [];
    
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      items.push({
        question: doc.id,
        answers: Object.values(doc.data()),
      });
    });

    setState(items);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getdata();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((item) => (
        <React.Fragment key={item.question}>
          <p className="question">{item.question}</p>
          {item.answers.map((answer) => (
            <p className="answer" key={answer}>
              {answer}
            </p>
          ))}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, but now i have following error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function at getdata     That error is in line 13

Comment: @nobodylikeyou: If `snapshot.map` is not a function then `snapshot` is not an array.  When you debug, what is it?  Why do you expect it to be an array?

Comment: @nobodylikeyou I incorrectly assumed snapshot was an array. I have updated the code to use the forEach method as in your original code.